# Explain the forces involved in this scenario

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, torque

[Scroll to question **5**](http://pmt.physicsandmathstutor.com/download/Maths/A-level/M5/Papers-Edexcel/June%202011%20QP%20-%20M5%20Edexcel.pdf)

[Solutions](http://pmt.physicsandmathstutor.com/download/Maths/A-level/M5/Papers-Edexcel/June%202011%20MS%20-%20M5%20Edexcel.pdf)

The question describes a rod in rotational equilibrium (under gravity) and asks for the forces on the 'axis' of the rod. I don't understand their derivation of 'X'. Surely the frictional force must be infinite in order to counter the torque at a distance of 0 from the pivot?

Comment: The question is rather confusing for a public examination.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with "friction," but you are right in thinking something is wrong with the given solution.

The free body diagram drawn in the solution is incomplete, because there is also a moment applied to the rod at P. Otherwise, the rod would not rotate at constant angular speed - it would slow down on the way up, and speed up again on the way down. To make it rotate at constant speed, you need some sort of motor and brake which would apply the correct time-dependent moment at P.

However since the question only asks for the *forces* at P, I suppose a pedantic examiner could argue that a moment isn't a force.But if somebody also calculated the moment, I would hope they wouldn't lose any marks!

The rest of the solution applies $F = ma$ in the along the rod and perpendicular to it. The "missing" moment doesn't appear in those two equations.

To find the moment, you would take moments about some point to get a third equation. Point P would be a good choice.

Comment: but at point P,  the applied moment can only be zero, because the distance from pivot is 0?

Comment: No, the applied moment is an external force. You can apply any magnitude of moment to any point on the structure, just as you can apply any magnitude of force to any point. In general the moment will cause an angular acceleration, but in this question it is needed to creates *zero* angular acceleration - i.e. to make the rod rotate at constant angular velocity as it says in the question.

Comment: ok, but you can apply a moment at the pivot?